# splitting an already in use subnet

Tags: ipv4, subnet, design

Note: the below examples are probably not realistic but work with the question.

Say I am attempting to plan for the future and I allocate a 10.1.0.0/16 for a certain floor of a building but do not subnet it, because I am unsure of what devices are going to be used because manglement. So people start moving into the floor and hooking up devices. At a certain point I can get a general idea of the device distribution and decide to split this subnet into 2, one for PC's and one for IP phones.

Is this possible to do on a running network without having to change the existing client's configuration.

If not, how easy is it to do in an environment with static addressing vs DHCP addressing?

Comment: I would put phones and PCs on separate VLANs and IP networks from the very start. I would also probably use a mask between 20 and 24 bits and just add networks as the number of devices grows.

Comment: What about overhead for routing between subsets

Comment: How about this: it's easier to make a subnet bigger than smaller. Use DHCP as much as you can, start with a small subnet and reduce the bit length of the subnet mask if and when necessary.

Comment: @ToddWilcox so making the subnet larger is easier than making it smaller. How would you manage multiple subnets?

Comment: With a router and dhcp server and dhcp relay and a VLAN for every subnet (or subnet for every VLAN really). And effective documentation. Technically that's how I DO manage multiple subnets and also how I WOULD manage multiple subnets if it all disappeared and I had to do it all over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Theory™, and In Practice™, this never goes well. Presumably devices of both types are scattered across the entire /16. Thus the devices within the LAN will have to be reconfigured.

If they *all* use DHCP, then it's a fairly simple process of changing the DHCP setup. *First*, drop the lease time to something unreasonably low to speed up convergence to the new subnets -- if your current lease is 1 week, you'll have a mess for at least a week before everything is forced to new settings; if the lease time has been dropped to 15min, it won't take so long.

However, no real world network is 100% DHCP. There are always static devices. So they will have to be changed manually. Which means you have to know well in advance which machines need attention.

---

A word on mis-matched subnet masks. This is, as a rule, **to be avoided**. However, in instances such as this, it will happen, however briefly. In the given example -- splitting a /16 into smaller subnets (2 /17's), the router between those two new subnets can facilitate "off-network" access through the practice of *proxy-arp*. Please note, this is the only acceptable exception for when proxy-arp should be allowed; and then, *as a temporary measure*.

Of course, the device still has to be in the correct subnet. The router interfaces will be /17's. A host in the wrong new subnet will be ignored by the router.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If two subnet's is what you need, why not use 10.1.0.0 /17 ?

That way, you can have 10.1.0.0 /17 for PC's and 10.1.128.0 /17 for IP phones.

You'll have 32766 hosts in each subnet.

Comment: I just used 2 subnets as an example. I would probably need more eventually